# Running and swimming in the morning combination

Tags: running, swimming, walking

I am going to Spain for 2 months.

The place is 1 km from the sea.

My question is what morning workout do you suggest for me?

I get up regularly at 6:05 in the morning every day and then I have time to 8:00.

What combination of actvities in the morning do you suggest?

Should I run on mon, wed, fri and swim on tue, thu and maybe on weekend?

I would like to have free weekends if possible (maybe except a little swimming).

I am not curious about intensity, but more about when to do what.

I mean, if I should run more or swim more.

Combining these two in one day is quite difficult, because running "wet" is a little dangerous.

But if you know some tips how to run after swimming (notice I don't want to run bare-foot or in flip-flops ;)), then let me know.

**EDIT:**

I am not a bodybuilder nor a triathlon athlete. My aim is to stay fit and sexy ;) therefore 45 - 60 min max for a morning workout. My main concern is that running can lead to knee/ankle injuries because I have 93kg and I am 187 cm tall. But I don't want to loose much weight I like how I look right now. Could the weight be the problem in the long time period? I was running 3 times a week (mo, we, fr) for 5 months now and I am quite accustomed to that, eventhough sometimes I walk for a while and not run all the way (especially if I staid up late at night the previous day). But I definitely see some progress. I don't run very long distances only about 5-6 km and I do some push ups, dips, pull ups etc.

Comment: What is your aim? If you are a beginner and if you are looking for something [like this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11578/starting-morning-routine-for-unfit-person) check it. May be useful.

Comment: My aim is to be fit and sexy ;). I am not a body builder nor triathlon athlete. Just want to find best running and swimming combination to stay in shape.

Comment: Then please take a look at the link in my previous comment and check if it suits you. Right now how good are you in swimming and running? Edit your question with this detail.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for edit which provides important information.

I'd say that your weight is ok for 187 cm sport man. If you are afraid of injuries you can try to use your forefoot while running. Your arch will automatically and NATURALLY absorb shocks. This type of running will lead to stronger calf muscles too. Or you can run on the beach where sand is absorbing shocks pretty well. Proper warm up is a must of course.

You are in a very good situation when even thinking about, let's say, 3 days running + 3 days swimming and 1 day rest. That's the ideal training ever. I'm very eager swimmer and as time goes by I experience more fun and more performance when I go "out of water" for some days. Combining swimming, running and gym for compensation exercise is the best way for long term sustainability.

That's all about providing necessary rest for particular muscle groups. Your legs (after hard run) will relax inside of water and vice versa. During running our arms, back and shoulders will taking a good rest and will be ready for tomorrow swimming again.

You can combine these 2 in one day but I'd suggest you to run first and then go to the water so your muscles, again, can take a rest and relax. Water pressure provides something like continuous massage.

Plus, there is another big advantage here too. This will be FUN for a long time. When you are swimming 6-7 times per week you are tired and you can find this boring. Maybe you can be even sick of it and experience very unpleasant burn out. (Ok, depends on motivation, competition etc. etc...) When doing 2 activities (maybe 3 actually: including push ups, pull ups after run) your workout will never be boring routine.

So good luck, keep moving and keep your very healthy life style!

EDIT: when to do what: just rotate your activities every day to avoid repeating one workout in 2 days. I'd plan my week like this: run+body, swim, run+body, swim, run+body, relax swim, rest.