# Is a high heart rate a sign to be concerned of?

Tags: health, heart-rate

Does a high heartrate indicate bad health / unfitness? I have a 80~85 BPM at resting state and it seems unusually high compared to the average. I don't exercise often, but I'm not necessary fat either - I'm 5"8 at 155 pounds.

Should I be concerned? If yes, what can I do to lower my BPM?

Comment: upvotes , because mine is 85-90 and i am 5'6'' with 75 kg and 31 years of age

Comment: General health questions are off topic.

Comment: This is definitely off-topic and is voted to close but then I would also suggest you try starting some cardio schedule. Follow [this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11578/starting-morning-routine-for-unfit-person/11580#11580)

Comment: Either a question is off topic or it isn't. How do you vote to close and provide an answer?

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this being off topic. It provides the basis for a solid question (What are resting heart rates for athletic/sedentary people?). Which is why I answered the way I did. I understand that this isn't the place for general health questions, though.

Comment: @Grohlier - Understood, but even asking the question about resting HR's for different cohorts isn't exercise related. (What's an average HR for an athlete instead of a sedentary person?)

Comment: @JohnP You convinced me.

Answer (score 1):

You are within the normal limits. Anything above 60 beats per minute and below 100 beats per minute is normal for a resting heart rate. Once your heart rate dips below 60 bpm, you are in Bardycardia (means slow heart). After breaching 100 bpm you are in Tachycardia (means fast heart).

Typically people that are more physically fit (cardiovascularly, not strength) have a lower resting heart rate than others that don't. However, this is not always the case. There are several medications (prescription and over the counter) that can both slow heart rates (like beta-blockers) or speed them up (think about pills with caffeine in them).

As long as you are not having any abnormal signs or symptoms (shortness of breath, light head, dizzy, confused, tunnel vision, chest pain, etc.) a heart rate between 60-100 should not be an issue. However, your primary care physician will be the best person to talk to about any concerns you might have. If they feel it is necessary they can refer you to a Cardiologist as well.

Everyone's heart rate is a little different. I have seen several athletes with resting heart rates in the 80s, and several geriatric patients (not on rate limiting medications) with heart rates in the 60s.